# how follow links on an initial post's response using python scrapy?

Tags: python, http-post, scrapy

so far I've done the following code.
The initial post gets done, as I see the prints, but no success on following links defined on the rules.

```
class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "myspider"
    rules = [
            Rule(
                # Define links to be followed and parsed
                SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=['xxx/xxx']), 
                callback='my_parse', 
                follow=True),
            ]

    def start_requests(self):
        print "start_requests"
        return [FormRequest(
            "http://domain/postUrl",
            formdata={
                'data1': '111', 
                'data2': '222',
                },
            callback=self.after_post
        )]

    def after_post(self, response):
        print "after_post"
        return

    def my_parse(self, response):
        print "my_parse"
        return
```

Thanks a lot in advance